# scala n-arity tree tail recursive evaluation

Tags: scala, recursion, tree, tail-recursion

I have a Tree structure, which is more general than a binary tree structure

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]

case class Leaf[A](value: Terminal[A]) extends Tree[A]
case class Node[A](op: Function[A], branches: Tree[A]*) extends Tree[A]
```

As you see, it can have a arbitrary number of branches.

I'm trying to make an evaluation method to be tail recursive but i'm  not being able to do it.

```
def evaluateTree[A](tree: Tree[A]): A = tree match {
  case Leaf(terminal) => terminal.value
  case Node(op: Function[A],  args @ _*) => op.operator((for (i <- args) yield evaluateTree(i)))
}
```

How can i save the stack manually?

Comment: How does it matter that it's got an arbitrary number of branches? How would you do tail recursion with a "simple" binary tree?

Comment: I don't have any solution right now but if regular tailrec is impossible, maybe you could consider using a [trampoline](http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/04/tail-calls-tailrec-and-trampolines.html) ?

Comment: the scala compiler unfolds a trampoline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was possible, using deep first search.

```
def evaluateTree[A](tree: Tree[A]): A = {
  @tailrec
  def evaluateWhile[C](l: List[Function[C]], arguments: List[List[C]], n_args: List[Int], f: Int => Boolean, acc: C): (List[Function[C]], List[List[C]], List[Int]) =
    n_args match {
      case h :: t if f(h) =>
        evaluateWhile(l.tail, arguments.tail, n_args.tail, f, l.head.operator(arguments.head ::: List(acc)))
      case h :: t  =>
        (l, (List(acc) ::: arguments.head) :: arguments.tail,  List(n_args.head - 1) ::: n_args.tail)
      case _ =>
        (l, List(acc) :: arguments, n_args)
    }
  @tailrec
  def DFS(toVisit: List[Tree[A]], visited: List[String] = Nil, operators: List[Function[A]] = Nil, arguments: List[List[A]] = Nil, n_args: List[Int] = Nil, debug: Int = 0): A = toVisit match {
    case Leaf(id, terminal) :: tail if !visited.contains(id) => {
      val (operators_to_pass, args_to_pass, n_args_to_pass) =
        evaluateWhile[A](operators, arguments, n_args, x => x == 1, terminal.value)
      DFS(toVisit.tail, visited ::: List(id), operators_to_pass, args_to_pass, n_args_to_pass, debug + 1)
    }
    case Node(id, op, args @_*) :: tail if !visited.contains(id) => {
      DFS(args.toList ::: toVisit.tail, visited ::: List(id), op :: operators, List(Nil) ::: arguments, List(args.length ) ::: n_args, debug + 1)
    }
    case _ => arguments.flatten.head
  }
  DFS(List(tree))
}
```

Comment: Congratulations on getting this figured out, but it would be really helpful if you could post compilable code.  In particular we need a working definition of `Terminal[A]` and `Function[A]`, and it appears you've changed the definition of `Leaf[A]` and `Node[A]`. (And you might want to remove the unused/unneeded `debug` argument.)

Answer (score 1):

If each `Node` can hold a different `op` then, no, I don't think tail recursion is possible.

If, on the other hand, you can feed all the `Leaf.value`s to a single `op` then it might be possible.

```
def evaluateTree[A](tree: Tree[A]): A = {
  @tailrec
  def allValues(branches: Seq[Tree[A]], acc: Seq[A] = Seq()): Seq[A] =
    if (branches.length < 1) acc
    else branches.head match {
      case Leaf(term) => allValues(branches.tail, term.value +: acc)
      case Node(_, args: Seq[Tree[A]]) => allValues(branches.tail ++ args, acc)
    }

  tree match {
    case Leaf(terminal) => terminal.value
    case Node(op: Function[A], args: Seq[Tree[A]]) => op.operator(allValues(args))
  }
}
```

I can't compile this as I don't have definitions for `Terminal` and `Function`, but it should be a reasonable outline of one approach to the problem.

Comment: Each node can indeed hold a different `op`. However each of this `op` in the end will receive an arbitrary number of `Leaf.value`

Comment: do you think it is possible?

Comment: No, I do not think it is possible. Tail recursion requires that the final recursion return a value that is unchanged as the stack is unwound. That can't happen if one `Node` returns the sum of its sub-values while the next `Node` returns the max of its sub-values, and the next `Node` does something completely different.